# ASP.NET - Problem in applying CSS elements to (child) page of Master

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have some CSS elements based on ids of HTML elements. e.g.

```
ul#subNav div
{   
    /*top:45px !important;*/
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #C6DEFF;
    border: 1px solid #5970B2;
    z-index:2020; 
}
```

Now, I cannot apply this style to a Webpage (ASP.NET Web form) based on a Master Page, since, at the time of rendering, The ID of UL "subnav"  changes to "ctl100_subnav" and hence browser no longer applies the CSS.

Any idea to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the SubNav div and apply CSS to the class and not to the ID.

Or you are using .net 4

> In order to avoid naming conflicts in controls, ASP.NET 2.0/3.5 used ClientID’s, which made each control generate the id attribute unique to that page. However these ID’s generated were long and unpredictable. Developers who have been doing Client-Side programming using a scripting language like JavaScript, have sorrow tales to tell when it came to referencing those ClientID’s in their scripts.
>
> ASP.NET 4.0 through the new ClientIDMode property, now gives  control back to the developer over the ClientID’s generated by ASP.NET controls. In my personal opinion, this was a good design decision taken by the ASP.NET team, since a lot of ASP.NET developers are using Client-side programming to enhance their interfaces and popular JavaScript frameworks like jQuery are getting more popular.

Comment: Agreed. But in case I am forced to use ID, is there any way out? (Am not using .NET 4.0. I use only ver 2.0)